# What's wrong with substituting $g(y) = 3$ into $f(z) = z^{5x + 1}$ to calculate $\frac{d\left(3^{(5x+1)}\right)}{dx}$?

Tags: proof-verification

I don't understand [this answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/15370/4655), but I've rewritten it to commence with $g(y) = 3$, to avoid ambiguity.

> The root of the difficulty is that $x$ appears free in $f(z)$, but we
> are trying to "capture" it with  $g(y)$, which is illegal. When we
> substitute $g(y)$ into $f(g(y))$, we have a variable clash:
>
> $$
>  f(g(\color{red} y)) = 3^{5\color{blue}x + 1} $$
>
> The red  $y$ is a *different variable* from the blue
> $x$.
>
> **The original expression [I emboldened]** had $x$ bound to the $\mathrm d x$, so by unbinding $\color{lightgreen}{it}$, we have changed the meaning of the expression:
>
> $$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d \color{blue} x} f(g(\color{red}y)) \ne
>  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d \color{red}y} f(g(\color{red}y))  $$

1. What exactly does it mean to "capture" $x$ with $g(y)$?
2. Why's this illegal?
3. What's the  **original expression**?
4. How was "$x$ bound to the $\mathrm d x$"?
5. What is  "$\color{lightgreen}{it}$"?
6. How did we unbind "$\color{lightgreen}{it}$"?

Comment: The attempt in the question is outrageously beautiful. Thank you for this question, I will bring it to the attention of some people I know!

Comment: Have you read the answer by user21820 below that? Personally it is the right explanation for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at the definition of $f(z) = z^{5x+1}$. So, $f$ is not only a function of $z$, but it is a function of two variables: $z$ and $x$, and they're not related to each other. By definition, $x$ can take any value which does not depend on $z$. So, the derivative of $f$ can be defined with respect to both $z$ and $x$, keeping the other variable constant. See [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) for more details. For the same reason, $(5x+1)z^{5x}$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $z$, not with respect to $x$. Thus, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}f(z,x)\neq (5x+1)z^{5x} = \frac{d}{dz}f(z,x)
\end{equation}
Writing $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = (5x+1)z^{5x}$ is referred to as illegal here.